# Heroku Flask Timeout

Tags: python, heroku

I have a Flask web app deployed on heroku and I'm using 2 professional dynos. When I try to make a request however it times out. This is caused by a web request that is fetching some sports stats.

When I run this on my local machine it runs instantly with no delays, but when I do it on heroku it takes >30 seconds.

Is there anyway to fix this? I am using the `nba_py` module to make the web requests for me.